# Cross Platform programming on C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, c-preprocessor

I want to make a program work and compile in both **WIN\Linux** .
I want to have some information about the **OS** which my program is ran on.
moreover I want to have a variable to decide about the code i want to be performed.

I thought about a pre-processed code to have an input to my controlling variable which I described.
So, I must have something like:

```
#  //a preprocess code to detect the os
# define controllingVar // ?
```

I use C++;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the WIN32 macro has been defined:

```
#ifdef WIN32
   // do windows stuff
#else
   // do GNU/Linux stuff
#endif
```

Note that on some compilers, you might also have to check for `_WIN32`, as stated in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Conditional_compilation).

As an example:

```
#ifdef WIN32
   void foo() {
       std::cout << "I'm on Windows!\n";
   }
#else
   void foo() {
       std::cout << "I'm on GNU/Linux!\n";
   }
#endif
```

**Edit**: since you're asking about different `main`s for each OS, here's an example:

```
int main() {
#ifdef WIN32
   // do whatever you want when executing in a Windows OS
#else
   // do the same for GNU/Linux OS.
#endif
}
```

You could also have different `main`s:

```
#ifdef WIN32
   int main() {
       //windows main
   } 
#else
   int main() {
       //GNU/Linux main
   } 
#endif
```

Comment: You can have code inside those defined, variable defitinitions, class definitions, whatever you want.

Comment: as you said i can have a variable and assign a value to it and use it in my program .and can I have 2 main function?

Comment: Yes, you could have one main function inside the windows part of the `ifndef` and another one in the `else` part.

Comment: thank you very much.the last Question:again about main function : can I have a main function running on both OSes with some different in two or three lines?

Comment: There you go, i eddited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can deduce what platform your code is being *compiled* for by using (compiler specific) pre-processor macros, like WIN32 and the like.  There is no easy way to deduce what platform your program is *running* on (other than it is most likely running on a platform it was compiled for) -- you will need to perform platform/OS specific calls for that.

You could do something like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32 // compiler specific, WIN32 is defined in Visual Studio
  // Windows specific code
  // include Windows specific headers
  int controllingVar = 0; // 0 - Windows
#else
  // For everything else
  // Here: assume Unix/Linux
  // include Linux specific headers
  int controllingVar = 1; // 1 - non-Windows
#endif
```

After this you can refer to `controllingVar` in your code.  `controllingVar` will have the value 0 if the program was compiled for Windows, 1 otherwise (and you can go with the assumption of Linux).

The `#ifdef` part enables conditional compilation -- the code within the Windows specific block is compiled only when compiled for Windows, the other in any other case.

Note that this essentially requires a duplication of coding, maintenance and testing efforts, so try to put only the most essential code in the conditional blocks and anything that is not platform specific outside it.

Comment: thanks ! you said that WIN32 is know by visual studio but what about dev-cpp?

Comment: Dev-C++ uses MinGW, which pre-defines WIN32, so you can use that as well